# Can't run Python programs in VS Code - 'cmd' is not recognized as an

Tags: python, windows, command-line, visual-studio-code

I've just installed the Python extension, restarted VS Code and updated it, but when I try to run a Python program and select the debugging configuration as (Python File), I get this message:

```
E:\SaifWork\code\workspaces\PY\self-taught dev>cd "e:\SaifWork\code\workspaces\PY\self-taught dev" && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Users\saif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe c:/Users/saif/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.18678/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 50135 "e:\SaifWork\code\workspaces\PY\self-taught dev\problem1.py" "
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have all the python directories added to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Python directories are added to the PATH, but your System32 (containing the cmd.exe, Windows’s command-line interpreter) isn’t. Try adding it manually.

EDIT: the System32 folder path is `%SystemRoot%\system32`, which is very often `C:\Windows\system32`.